# Showing how much bigger $|\mathbb{R}|$ is than $|\mathbb{N}|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, education

In one of my lectures to a group of Discrete Mathematics students (all of which are CS majors, not math), I go over the proof that the cardinality of the continuum is strictly larger in size than the cardinality of the naturals; ie the reals are uncountable.

This lesson closes out our disscussion on generalized functions, and I found students understand the proof of Cantor's argument fairly well. However, this proof only shows that there exists at least one real outside any bijective function, when in fact nearly all reals are excluded.

As stated [here](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4974)

> Which reals could possibly be “missing” from our universe? Every real you can name—42, π, √e, even uncomputable reals like Chaitin’s Ω—has to be there, right? Yes, and there’s the rub: every real you can name. Each name is a finite string of symbols, so whatever your naming system, you can only ever name countably many reals, leaving 100% of the reals nameless.
>
> Or did you think of only the rationals or algebraic numbers as forming a countable dust of discrete points, with numbers like π and e filling in the solid “continuum” between them? If so, then I hope you’re sitting down for this: every real number you’ve ever heard of belongs to the countable dust! The entire concept of “the continuum” is only needed for reals that don’t have names and never will.

Which is incredible, and I really want to convey this to my students as well, however I don't know of a good proof or argument that is at their level (so no measure theory) to show that "100%" of the real numbers are excluded from any possible function from $\mathbb{N}$

Clearing up my question so that it's easy to see exactly what I am asking for:

**Can it be proved using only basic set theory, functions, and calculus that "100%" of all real numbers are excluded from any function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?**

Comment: Without measure theory? Nope. Measure theory is literally designed for this kind of question. The best solution in my opinion to express how big the reals are is to show what other sets are countable (like $\mathbb N^n$ for all natural $n$).

Comment: To the extent that "100%" intuitively has any meaning, I think the concept will be intuitively obvious if you consider the question "what proportion of the real numbers are countable"  If we assume the answer is anything significant or measurable but the result of would imply the total number of reals must be countable.

Comment: What Don said. OTOH, these CS students may have fun exploring a related topic: the connection between [Mandelbrot & Julia sets](http://usefuljs.net/fractals/docs/julia_mandelbrot.html). Only Julia sets corresponding to points in the small region of the complex plane covered by M set are connected, all the other Julia sets are dusts.

Comment: @DonThousand Supposing that measure theory is a requirement, what would a proof of this look like? Is there an intuitive meaning you know of for a set having measure 0?

Comment: Here's what I would probably say: Any countable set is so small that it's removal from the set of real numbers gives a set "just as big" as the set of real numbers.

Comment: @wjmccann Lee’s answer essentially answers this follow up of yours too. A measure zero set is one which can be covered by collections of intervals of arbitrarily small total length.

Comment: In your voice: "Let's consider all the fractions of the form $1/n$. They are just as numerous as $\mathbb{N}$, right? How dense do you think they are in the $[0,1]$ interval? Wait, scratch that, let's go crazy and consider all fractions of the form $n/d$ with $n<d$." And then you argue like 3Blue1Brown did in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyW5z-M2yzw (starting at 5:30, but watch it all if you haven't already)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although measure theory is of course needed to do this formally, perhaps there's a way to discuss this with your students informally.

You could argue like this.

List the numbers: $x_1 = f(1)$, $x_2 = f(2)$, $x_3 = r(3)$,...

Draw a sketch of the first few on a number line; it doesn't matter exactly where you put them.

Surround $x_1$ with an interval labelled $I_1$ of total length $1/2$, going from $x_1-1/4$ to $x_1 + 1/4$.

Next, surround $x_2$ with an interval labelled $I_2$ of togal length $1/4$, going from $x_2 - 1/8$ to $x_2 + 1/8$. So, the total length of $I_1$ and $I_2$ is at most $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$.

And now continue. At the $n$th stage, you'll have intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ whose lengths total up to $1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$.

And so, even if you continue letting $n$ go to infinity and take all the intervals all together, their lengths will total up to at most $1$! How can that possibly cover the entire real number line, which has infinite length?

If you wanted to, you could repeat this, *except* that you can start with $I_1$ having length $.00005$ instead of $.5$; the total lengths will total up to at most $.0001$!

Comment: This is really good! So in the limit as the length of the starting interval approaches $0$ around our first point, the sum as a whole approaches $0$, which is a kind of cheeky way of showing that it is measure $0$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. In fact, that's the *formal* way of showing it has measure 0, assuming the formalities have been developed.

Comment: From a non maths student's perspective we can ask them to imagine the difference between the number of elements in a set A and its power set P(A) when A has 100,1000,10000, ....elements. And in the limiting case when it becomes infinite!

Comment: @LawrenceMano: I think that is a very bad suggestion. If $A_i$ is a sequence of finite subsets of a set $A$ with $\bigcup_iA_i = A$, then $\bigcup_i \Bbb{P}{A_i}$ is countably infinite - it falls way short of $\Bbb{P}{A}$, if $A$ is infinite.

Comment: @RobArthan It's just to emphasize that power set of N is uncountable. It's for a non maths student who doesn't know measure theory. I just ask the student to watch cardinality of A and cardinality of power set of A and note the relative increases.

Comment: @LawrenceMano: let me write $\Bbb{F}(X)$ for the set of finite subsets of $X$. Then what you say about the sizes of a finite set $A$ and $\Bbb{P}(A)$ if equally true of $A$ and $\Bbb{F}(A)$. But in the "limiting case", $\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{N})$ is uncountable but $\Bbb{F}(\Bbb{N})$ is countable. You are asking your students to be motivated by a fallacious argument.

Comment: @RobArthan I accept your argument. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to see the point. Sorry to harp on about it. Also (correcting an insane typo in a comment I made yesterday): I now think was a bit harsh saying "very bad":  for "very bad" read "potentially unhelpful".